# Does Django have a template tag that can detect URLs and turn them into hyperlinks?

Tags: python, django, http, templates, url

When someone writes a post and copies and pastes a url in it, can Django detect it and render it as a hyperlink rather than plain text?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Django has the [urlize template filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) which will automatically detect both URLs and email addresses and turn them into the appropriate hyperlinks.

The docs there are actually a little thin, so I recommend also reading the [docstring in the source for the urlize function](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/html.py#L226) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

urlize:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#urlize

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to parse plain text in some way, for example as reStructuredText (my favourite) or Markdown (Stack Overflow uses a slightly modified variant of Markdown). These will both turn valid plain text links targets into hyperlinks. This also gives you more power over what you can do; you won't need to resort to HTML to achieve some basic formatting. Note also as stated with `urlize` that you should only use it on plain text; it's not designed to be mixed with HTML.