# Make links clickable in my Django TextField

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

I have a Textfield like so:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=650, blank=True, null=True)
```

When someone posts a link in the `TextField`, e.g. [www.stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/), I want it to be clickable (nested in an `<a>` tag). Is there any way to do this with code and not using a text editor?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the [**`urlize`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) template filter tag for this. So instead of writing:

```
{{ some_comment.comment_text }}
```

you should write:

```
{{ some_comment.comment_text|urlize }}
```

According to the documentation, we then get:

> **Converts URLs and email addresses** in text into clickable links.
>
> This template tag works on links prefixed with `http://`, `https://`,
>   or `www.`. For example, `https://goo.gl/aia1t` will get converted but
>   `goo.gl/aia1t` won’t.
>
> It also supports domain-only links ending in one of the original top
>   level domains (`.com`, `.edu`, `.gov`, `.int`, `.mil`, `.net`, and
>   `.org`). For example, `djangoproject.com` gets converted.
>
> (..)
>
> If value is `"Check out www.djangoproject.com"`, the output will be
>   `"Check out <a href="http://www.djangoproject.com"
>   rel="nofollow">www.djangoproject.com</a>"`.

A related template filter is [**`urlizetrunc`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#urlizetrunc) where the links are not only clicable, but truncated as well. For example:

```
{{ some_comment.comment_text|urlizetrunc:15 }}
```

In that case the URLs the *user sees* (of course not the link itself) is truncated to 15 characters, since links can be quite long and chaotic.

Answer (score 1):

[Some other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465636/does-django-have-a-template-tag-that-can-detect-urls-and-turn-them-into-hyperlin)

> Django has the [urlize template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) which will automatically detect both URLs and email addresses and turn them into the appropriate hyperlinks.
>
> The docs there are actually a little thin, so I recommend also reading the docstring in the source for the urlize function for more information.